# Why does Ruby YAML sometimes add '2' after pipe char (|)?

Tags: ruby, yaml

In working with Ruby module YAML, I've come across a behavior I don't understand.

String#to_yaml for a multiline string sometimes adds character '2' just after the pipe character:  '|2' vs. just '|'.

In particular, it does this when the first line is empty.

Any clue as to why?

Here's an example:

```
C:\Users\Burdette>irb
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.2.6"
irb(main):002:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> s = <<EOT
irb(main):004:0" 1
irb(main):005:0" 2
irb(main):006:0" 3
irb(main):007:0" EOT
=> "1\n2\n3\n"
irb(main):008:0> puts s.to_yaml
--- |
  1
  2
  3
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> s = "\n" + s
=> "\n1\n2\n3\n"
irb(main):010:0> puts s.to_yaml
--- |2

  1
  2
  3
=> nil
irb(main):011:0> exit
```

Comment: That `2` is an _indentation indicator_, it says that the block is indented by 2 spaces.

Comment: I did not indent.  Does the empty line amount to a request for indentation?  Also, if I indent each line 4 spaces, that spacing is honored, and I still get '|2', both with and with and without the leading empty line.

Answer (score 9):

`|` indicates a literal scalar. It is followed by a [Block Scalar Header](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793718) which can indicate the indentation level of the literal and whether or not it is "chomped". Chomping is whether or not to strip the final newline. For example, when we remove the last newline...

```
2.4.3 :059 > puts "\n1\n2\n3".to_yaml
--- |2-

  1
  2
  3
 => nil
```

...YAML adds a `-` to indicate that the final newline is removed.

Similarly, the `2` says to remove the first two spaces from each line. This allows leading newlines in the original string to be preserved.

```
2.4.3 :061 > puts "\n  1\n2\n3".to_yaml
--- |2-

    1
  2
  3
 => nil
```

Normally the indentation level is blank, so you just see `|`, and the indentation value is inferred from the first line non-empty line. In this example, 2 is inferred.

```
2.4.3 :062 > puts "1\n2\n3".to_yaml
--- |-
  1
  2
  3
 => nil
```

But when the first line contains ambiguities, it must be made explicit. Here's the full docs from the spec on that.

> [8.1.1.1. Block Indentation Indicator](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793979)
>
> Typically, the indentation level of a block scalar is detected from its first non-empty line. It is an error for any of the leading empty lines to contain more spaces than the first non-empty line.
>
> Detection fails when the first non-empty line contains leading content space characters. Content may safely start with a tab or a “#” character.
>
> When detection would fail, YAML requires that the indentation level for the content be given using an explicit indentation indicator. This level is specified as the integer number of the additional indentation spaces used for the content, relative to its parent node.
>
> It is always valid to specify an indentation indicator for a block scalar node, though a YAML processor should only emit an explicit indentation indicator for cases where detection will fail.

In your case, the YAML round trips just fine with or without the explicit indicator. It can get the indentation from the first non-empty line. I'd imagine that particular YAML implementation is being conservative and making the indentation explicit when the first line is blank.

There's many ways to express the same thing in YAML. For example, adding an extra leading space and Ruby switches to quotes.

```
2.4.3 :055 > puts " \n1\n2\n3\n".to_yaml
--- " \n1\n2\n3\n"
 => nil
```

Why not this?

```
--- |2-
   
  1
  2
  3
```

Probably because it's not easy to read and that extra space is very easy to miss when being ready a human, YAML is for humans as well as machines. To really know you'll have to read the code of the YAML library and probably online discussions during its development. I'm going to guess that it was decided being explicit when there is any possibility of ambiguity or confusion is safer.

Comment: Thanks much, Schwern!

I looked at this very document, but did not know what terms to search for.  I looked at every '|' character in it, trying to find one that's followed by a number.